# A multiparameter inequality

Tags: real-analysis, inequality, asymptotics, analytic-number-theory

Let $x\ge 2$ be a real number and $\nu=:\nu(x)$ an integer-valued function. Let $I$ be an interval of $\mathbb{R}$ such that $\lambda(I)<(\log\nu)^{-1/2}$ where $\lambda$ denotes the Lebesgue measure on $\mathbb{R}$. I am trying to find only one condition on $\nu,x$ and $\lambda(I)$ which guarantee that
$$\frac{\log x}{x\lambda(I)^2}\le M\frac{\lambda(I)}{\nu \log\nu}$$
for some constant $M>0$.
Can someone help with this concern?
My guess: I think that the condition $\nu>C(\log x)^2$ (independent on $m$ $x$ and $\lambda(I)$) for some constant $C>0$ is enough to prove the above equality. But I failed to prove that.

Comment: May I ask what you mean by 'integral valued function'?

Comment: @MengchunZhang, I only mean that the target of the function $\nu$ is $\mathbb{N}$

Comment: Oh I see, sorry that I misinterpreted 'integral', this is clear now!

Answer (score 2):

First we must have $\nu>1$ due to $0\leq\lambda(I)<(\log\nu)^{-1/2}$. With this, rearrange the inequality to get
$$(\nu\log\nu)\frac{\log x}x\leq M\lambda^3(I)<M(\log\nu)^{-3/2}$$
$$\Rightarrow\quad\nu(\log\nu)^{5/2}\leq\frac{Mx}{\log x}.$$
Using the log-bound $\nu(\log\nu)^{5/2}\leq4(\nu-1)^2$ for all $\nu>1$, it is sufficient to have
$$1<\nu\leq1+\sqrt{\frac{Mx}{4\log x}}.$$
If we want to further simplify the bound, use $\log x\leq x^{1/2}$ to get
$$1<\nu\leq 1+Cx^{1/4}$$
for some constant $C\leq\sqrt M/2$.

---

Proof of the log-bound:

Let $f(x)=4(x-1)^2-x(\log x)^{5/2}$, we show $f(x)\geq0$ for all $x\geq1$.

Since $f(1)=0$, we only need to show $f'(x)\geq0$ for $x\geq1$. To this end, find
$$f'(x)=4(x-1)-(\log x)^{5/2}-(5/2)(\log x)^{3/2}.$$
We prove the following claim
$$(\log x)^p\leq a(x-1)\quad\forall\,x\geq1,p\geq1,a>0\ \text{such that}\ \frac1{p-1}\left(\frac ap\right)^{\frac1{p-1}}\geq e^{-1}.$$
Let $g(x)=a(x-1)-(\log x)^p$, since $g(1)=0$ we need $g'(x)=a-p(\log x)^{p-1}/x\geq0$, or equivalently, $$\log x\leq(ax/p)^{1/(p-1)}. \tag{$\star$}$$
It is easy to verify $\alpha x^\beta-\log x$ attains minimum at $x=(\alpha\beta)^{-1/\beta}$ for any $\alpha,\beta>0$. Hence, we need $\alpha\beta\geq e^{-1}$ for $\alpha x^\beta\geq\log x$. Taking this into $(\star)$ with $\alpha=(a/p)^{1/(p-1)}$ and $\beta=1/(p-1)$, we get the claim.

Using the claim, we obtain the following bound
$$(\log x)^{5/2}\leq2(x-1)\quad\text{and}\quad(\log x)^{3/2}\leq\frac45(x-1).$$
Taking these into $f'(x)$ and we obtain $f'(x)\geq0$ and thus the log-bound.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. I think that you need $c^3$ for the second displayed inequality. Furthermore,  I am looking for a condition in which the constant involved in the inequality does not depend on $m$ or $\lambda(I)$. In the condition you gave the constant $c$ depends on $m$ or $\lambda(I)$.

Comment: @HaitamH Many thanks for the comment, I think I get the idea now, so it's $\lambda(I)$ dependent on $\nu$ and not the other way around. In this case, we no longer need $\lambda(I)=c(\log\nu)^{-1/2}$ and the answer has been updated. Let me know if there are mistakes, thanks!

Comment: But I am still not sure how to make it independent of $M$, unless there are other conditions on $M$.

Comment: Thank you for the update.